# Is it possible to prove that $\pi(n)>\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$ for all $n > 10$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it possible to prove that the number of prime numbers between $0$ and $n$ is greater than the number of prime numbers between $n$ and $2n$, for all $n > 10$? 
$$\pi(n)>\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$$

By the prime number theorem, we know that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(n)\pi(n)}{n}=1$$

so:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\pi(n)=\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\pi(2n)=\frac{2n}{\ln(2n)}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\pi(n)}{\pi(2n)}=\frac{n\ln(2n)}{2n\ln(n)}=\frac{\ln(2n)}{2\ln(n)}$$

We know that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{ln(2n)}{2ln(n)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

therefore:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\pi(n)}{\pi(2n)}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2\pi(n)=\pi(2n)$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\pi(n)=\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$$

This suggest that my inequality is false for $n=\infty$ because:
$$\pi(\infty)=\pi(2\infty)-\pi(\infty)$$

Also, someone told me that since the relation between $\pi(n)$ and $\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$ is asymptotic, there are infinitely many n for which:
$$\pi(n)<\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$$

but except for $n=2,4,10$, where the difference between $\pi(n)$ and $\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$ is $0$, the result of $\left(\pi(n)\right)-\left(\pi(2n)-\pi(n)\right)$ seems to grow slowly as n grows. Since the density of primes decrease as n grows, i don't understand how there could be more prime numbers between $n$ and $2n$ than between $0$ and $n$...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We need some [nonasymptotic bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function).  To get both of the below bounds, we need $x\ge 60184$; these were proved by [Dusart](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442) in 2010.

$$\frac{x}{\log x -1}<\pi(x)<\frac{x}{\log x-1.1}$$

Hence, $$2\pi(x)-\pi(2x)>\frac{2x}{\log x-1}-\frac{2x}{\log(2x)-1.1}=2x\left(\frac{1}{\log x-1}-\frac{1}{\log x+\log 2 -1.1}\right)$$
Because $\log 2-1.1\approx -0.4$, $$\log x-1 < \log x +\log 2-1.1$$

Hence the RHS is positive, and the OP's claim is true for $x\ge 60184$; we leave $10\le x\le 60184$ for someone willing to do the computation.

---

Note: the result holds because $2>e^{0.1}\approx 1.105$.  Hence, it can be strengthened, by replacing $2$ by a smaller constant, e.g. $$1.2\pi(x)-\pi(1.2x)>0$$ (holding  for all $x\ge 60184$)

Comment: i just did the computation up to 60184  and it holds