# Is $p_{2n} > 2 p_n$?

Tags: number-theory

According to the prime number theorem $p_n \sim n \log n$ so $p_{2n} \sim 2 p_n$, asymptotically. But I believe it should be possible to show that $p_{2n} > 2 p_n$. Any ideas to get the ball rolling welcome.

Edit: I tried several examples -- here's one -- $p_{481} = 3433$, $p_{962}=7577 > 2 p_{481}$; the examples I tried support the inequality.

Comment: Did you try any examples?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838067/is-it-possible-to-prove-that-pin-pi2n-pin-for-all-n-10) which, essentially, shows the opposite of the inequality you ask about.

Comment: @lulu: unless I’m mistaken, it’s “counterpart” rather than opposite.

Comment: Please, for my education -- can you explain why this is being voted down? I don't post here often and it seems (to me) that I've met the criteria sufficient  to ask a question (some "research effort" and "useful" to me). I've tried to solve this myself (by studying the derivation of the PNT and the Riemann hypothesis) and trying several examples (which I neglected to mention) and applying the PNT. Should I state all of this background for each question I post? It's an easy question to state but I don't believe it's obvious to rigorously prove.

Comment: @lulu I think you misread the question. The inequality OP is asking about seems to be true for $n>1$.

Comment: @lulu It seems if you substitute $n = p_m$ into the answer to that question, you get exactly what the OP wants instead of the opposite.

Comment: @lulu: The question you cited regards the prime counting function. Are you suggesting that this can be used to rigorously prove the inequality in my post? I think you're just restating the comment I made in my question. Thanks in advance for the explanation.

Comment: Both this question and the linked question concern the density of primes on $[0,x]$ compared to $[x, 2x]$. They phrase it differently. The linked question asks specifically about the count of primes in each interval, while this question asks about whether $[0,p_n]$ is ever longer than $[p_n, p_{2n}]$. If it turns out that there are more primes in $[p_n, 2p_n]$ than in $[0, p_n]$, then clearly the interval $[p_n, p_{2n}]$ must be shorter, and vice versa. Apart from some possible subtle shenanigans at the end points of these intervals, I see them as more or less the same question.

Comment: I’ll just provide a proof based on the answer in the question @lulu linked. Indeed, the answer there says $2\pi(n) > \pi(2n)$ for all $n > 10$. Substitute $n = p_m$ for $m > 4$ gives $\pi(p_{2m}) = 2m = 2\pi(p_m) > \pi(2p_m)$. Hence, $p_{2m} > 2p_m$ for all $m > 4$. By direct calculation, this is also true for $m = 2, 3, 4$ as well. So $p_{2m} > 2p_m$ for all $m > 1$.

Comment: @DavidGao: if you want to make this an answer, including statements regarding  nonasymptotic and (not explicitly shown in the cited answer) $x < 60184$ regions, I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838067/is-it-possible-to-prove-that-pin-pi2n-pin-for-all-n-10) cited by @lulu, $2\pi(n) > \pi(2n)$ for all $n > 10$. The result for $n \geq 60184$ is proved by using nonasymptotic bounds on $\pi(n)$ in the accepted answer there. The OP there said in the comments that they did the computation up to 60184 to verify the remaining cases. I also performed this calculation myself and verified that $2\pi(n) > \pi(2n)$ is also true for $10 < n < 60184$. The Mathematica code I used is provided here, in case anyone want to run this calculation themselves:

```
c = 0;
For[n = 11, n < 60184, n++,
  c += If[2 PrimePi[n] <= PrimePi[2 n], 1, 0]];
Print[c]
```

Since $p_5 = 11$, for any $m > 4$ we may substitute $n = p_m$ into this result to obtain $\pi(p_{2m}) = 2m = 2\pi(p_m) > \pi(2p_m)$. Hence, $p_{2m} > 2p_m$ for all $m > 4$. When $m = 2$, $p_4 = 7 > 2 \cdot 3 = 2p_2$. When $m = 3$, $p_6 = 13 > 2 \cdot 5 = 2p_3$. When $m = 4$, $p_8 = 19 > 2 \cdot 7 = 2p_4$. Thus, we have $p_{2m} > 2p_m$ for all $m \geq 2$.

(One final note: This is not true for $m = 1$, as $p_2 = 3 < 2 \cdot 2 = 2p_1$.)